# Pre-Signed URL for S3 Bucket URL: Options Available

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am able to generate presigned URL for an S3 object using php. But it has X-Amz-Credential parameter which contains AWS Access Key ID as value; Is it Ok? Can we generate pre-signed url without this parameter; Also it displays the entire S3 File URL, is it not? If we do not want S3 Url to be displayed, is CloudFront Distribution mandatory? Is there no other way for pre-signed URL?

Comment: It is okay for your Access Key to be known -- it's just like a Username. However, keep the Secret Key private. Using CloudFront won't fully obscure the name (Key) of an S3 object. Is there a particular reason why you don't want the URL visible?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. URL not being displayed, is part of the general requirement of Securing S3 Bucket URLs. Our specific requirement is, that direct full S3 URLs, when using in a mobile app, are being used from outside the app. FYI I have Created Distribution also and am generating CloudFront Presigned URLs...

Answer (score 0):

We serve specific assets from S3 via Cloudfront Distribution Pre-signed URL's only - [direct access to S3 is forbidden](https://medium.com/tide-engineering-team/block-public-s3-bucket-access-with-cloudfront-oai-dc7f442f42a5) via bucket policy.

It works like this:

1. The backend creates the Pre-singed URL and sends it as a response to to the frontend
2. The frontend requests the asset
3. The asset is served via the Cloudfront Distribution

This is the data that the client can see in the request/response

Request:

```
:authority assets.yourdistribution.com (not your S3 bucket name)
:path /images/whatever.jpg?Expires=123&Key-Pair=Something&Signature=123mmmsd...
.. other uninteresting fields
```

Response:

```
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-cf-id: SomeIdString
Via: your.distribution.com (not bucket name)
.. other uninteresting fields
```

There is no full S3 path data, neither credential params.

If this is what you need, you can read [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html) on how to generate CloudFront Pre-Signed URL's.

Also another thing - [obscurity is not security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)